# Why does Amanda Rogers have human physiology?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q

Amanda Rogers eats (presumably due to being hungry), has a heart rate, blood pressure, and other vital signs, and even cries. Why? Her parents were both Q. Wouldn't she be fully Q, too? Is it because her parents "masqueraded" as humans that Amanda was also born with human needs and physiology?

Also, Amanda is clearly shown to not be omniscient (or even extremely knowledgeable). (For example, she can't imagine how much energy is produced in the warp core.) Is this because, again, she was "given" the normal physiology of a human? But why?

Comment: I think this is a good example of a question that's getting downvoted because it's trivially simple to answer.

Comment: I guess it depends whether you believe "assumed human form" to obviously mean becoming a human/Q hybrid, instead of, you know, simply masquerading as a human. I think the criticism is unwarranted, but whatever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q addresses this in the episode. In short, her parents created human bodies to inhabit. These meat-puppets were apparently sufficiently realistic (DNA, naughty bits, etc) as to be able to conceive a real human child, albeit one whose Q nature eventually shone through.

> **BEVERLY:** *How is that possible? Her parents... her biological parents... were human.*
>
> **Q:** *Not exactly.*
>
> They regard him curiously.
>
> **Q:** *They had assumed human form... in order to visit Earth. For an amusement, I suppose... but in vulgar human fashion they proceeded to
> conceive a child.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: True Q](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/232.txt)</sup></sub>

It's a testament to the power of the Q that they were able to create human bodies from scratch, and not just in the old-fashioned way.

Comment: "Assume" human form doesn't necessarily mean that they created "real" human bodies to inhabit, down to the very DNA. Q assumes human form all of the time. Besides, why would you need a literal human body to visit Earth?

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - The fact that they had a human child while in human form would strongly imply that they didn't just animate a hollow shell, they created real human bodies.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon: “Q assumes human form all of the time.” *Does* he? Or is that just what it looks like?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Ah, now that's a different (and possibly answerable) question.

Comment: Unfortunately, it'd be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - Not if you ask for evidence.

Comment: Thanks, Richard, for answering my stupid and unnecessary question!

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM